# erro laravel "Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::$email"

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'm doing a login and registration screen, the registration screen is perfect, but the login screen is giving me a headache to authenticate.

the registration is done, but as soon as I log in it gives this error...

"Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::$email"

I don't know what else to do to make it work.

CONTROLLER:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use App\Models\Usuario;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Request;


class Usuarios extends Controller
{
    public function cadastrar()
    {
        $usuario = new Usuario(Request::all());
        $usuario->save();
        return redirect('/')->with('mensagem_sucesso', 'Cadastro efetuado com sucesso!');

    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('layout/cadastrousuario');
    }

    public function indexlogin()
    {
        return view('layout/login');
    }

    public function logar(Request $request)
    {

        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request-> password])) {
            dd('voce esta logado');
        } else {
            dd('voce nao esta logado');
        }

    }

}
```

MODEL:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Model\Request;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class Usuario  extends Authenticatable
{

    protected $table = 'usuario';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable =
        array(
            "codigo",
            "nome",
            "email",
            "apelido",
            "senha",
            "bloqueado",
            "saldo",
            "saldo_atual",
            "admin"
        );


    use HasFactory;
}
```

ROUTE:

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\Lancamentos;
use App\Http\Controllers\LancamentosSimplificado;
use App\Http\Controllers\Usuarios;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

// Route = (rota)::get ou post = (method) ( '/home' = (link) , [Lancamentos = (controller) :: class, 'logar' = ( function) ;

Route::get('/', [Lancamentos::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/salvar', [Lancamentos::class, 'salvar']);
Route::get('/maisdetalhes/{codigo}', [Lancamentos::class, 'maisdetalhes']);
Route::get('/criarchat', [Lancamentos::class, 'criarchat']);
Route::post('/cadastrar', [Lancamentos::class, 'cadastrar']);
Route::post('/cadastrar-simplificado', [LancamentosSimplificado::class, 'cadastrar']);
Route::get('/criarchat', [LancamentosSimplificado::class, 'listar']);
Route::get('/chat/{codigo}', [Lancamentos::class, 'chat']);
Route::get('/chatcriado/{codigo}', [LancamentosSimplificado::class, 'chatcriado']);
Route::get('/cadastrar-usuario', [Usuarios::class, 'index']);
Route::post('/cadastrar-usuario', [Usuarios::class, 'cadastrar']);
Route::get('/login', [Usuarios::class, 'indexlogin']);
Route::post('/login', [Usuarios::class, 'logar']);
```

page image as soon as I click login

Comment: Using `$request->get('email')` will account for missing inputs (returns null if the input doesn't exist), but you do want to actually fix why it's missing. You don't show your login form, but make sure your inputs are there and have the names that you're looking for.

Comment: you have an instance of the Facade for the Request, not the Request class itself ... you need to alias `Illuminate\Http\Request` if you want to inject an instance of the Request class, `\Request` is the facade for the Request class which you make static calls to

Comment: @lagbox Actually that's the correct error for the correct Request. They have `use Request`, and I verified locally that a missing input throws the Facade error.

Comment: One thing you may want to do is use [validation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation) either at the top of your function or as a Form Request to make sure all inputs exist before attempting to use them

Comment: @aynber the error is because they are getting an instance of the Facade, which you don't do, they are static proxies ... if they want an instance of the Request they have to use `Illuminate\Http\Request` or they use the Facade as a static proxy by calling static methods

Answer (score 0):

to start you have to make validations in the register function to be sure that the email address arrives well and is registered. i would start by modifying this function

```
public function cadastrar(Request $r)
 {
   $r->validate([
     'name' => 'required|string',
     'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
     'password' => 'min:6',
     'password_confirmation' => 'required_with:password|same:password|min:6',
     'custom_field' => 'custom validation'

 ]);
 $input = $r->all();
 $input['password'] = Hash::make($r->password);
 $utilisateur = Model::create($input); //the Model == Usuario;
 return redirect('/')->with([
    'message'    => "Cadastro efetuado com sucesso!",
    'alert-type' => 'success',
]);
}
```

this is just a code snippet, I don't pretend to say that it's exactly what you need.the next way is the login function

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $r->email, 'password' => $r->password])) {
                // The user is active, not suspended, and exists.
                $user = Auth::user();
                if($user->fcm_token != Null){
                    $token = $user->createToken('AUTH')->accessToken;
                    $user->remember_token = $token;
                    $user->device_token = $user->fcm_token;
                    $user->save();
                    $response = [
                        "data"=> [
                            'user'=> $user,
                            'token'=> $token,
                        ],
                        'message_fr' => 'Utilisateur connecté avec succès',
                        'message_en' => 'User logged successfully',
                    ];
                    return response()->json($response, 200);
                }else{
                    $response = [
                        'message_fr' => 'Vous êtes peut-être un robot',
                        'message_en' => 'You may be a robot',
                    ];
                    return response()->json($response, 422);
                }
            } else {
                $response = [
                    'message_fr' => 'Veuillez vérifier vos informations de connexion',
                    'message_en' => 'Please check your login information',
                ];
                return response()->json($response, 422);
            }
```

since you put a validation on the register, you are sure that the email is not only present, but also conforms to the nomenclature of an email

these two methods presented are examples taken from my source code of an available project, Good luck to you

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong Request class. `Request` (`Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request`) that is aliased in `config/app.php` is the Facade, static proxy, for the bound Request class instance, `Illuminate\Http\Request`. If you want an instance of a Request you need to be using `Illuminate\Http\Request`.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Now via dependency injection you will have an instance of the Request class (which has magic methods to access inputs via dynamic properties). If you keep what you have then you would not be asking for an instance via dependency injection and would have to use the Facade as a Facade:

```
public function logar()
{
    ...
    $something = Request::input(...); // static call to Facade
    ...
}
```